# Why more than two android flavor dimensions don't work properly?

Tags: android, gradle, android-flavors, android-flavordimension

Here is a problem, for example, I need the next three dimensions for my app: "brand", "environment", "market". The configuration will look like this:

```
flavorDimensions "brand", "environment", "market"

productFlavors {
    // brand
    nike{
        dimension "brand"
        applicationId "com.android.nike"
    }
    adidas{
        dimension "brand"
        applicationId "com.android.adidas"
    }

    // environment
    test{
        dimension "environment"
        applicationIdSuffix ".test"
    }
    prod {
        dimension "environment"
    }

    // market
    google {
        dimension "market"
    }
    amazon {
        dimension "market"
    }
}
```

As a result, I can build the next 8 applications (I ignoring build types in this example):

```
nikeTestGoogle
nikeTestAmazon
nikeProdGoogle
nikeProdAmazon
adidasTestGoogle
adidasTestAmazon
adidasProdGoogle
adidasProdAmazon
```

As I understand documentation about flavor dimensions (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#flavor-dimensions), application nikeTestGoogle use files from the next folders: main, nike, test, google, nikeTest, nikeTestGoogle. But it doesn't work, Android studio sees only files in main, nike, test, google, and nikeTestGoogle. Files in nikeTest ignored and even doesn't mark as currently active.

Does anyone know why it happened?

Comment: `amazon` belongs to dimension `services` but there is no dimension `services`.

Comment: I believe this is by design. You get each individual flavor, each individual build type (debug, release), cartesian product of all flavors, and cartesian product of all flavors with build type. You don't get just some of the flavors together, or some of the falvors with build type.

Comment: That's my mistake, of course I mean "market", not "services" for "amazon". I am already edited that.

Comment: @OlegNestyuk Did you find any solution for this? I'm also using 2 flavorDimensions but after Syncing it's building only productFlavors x buildTypes

Comment: @Astha seems like this is normal behavior. I asked this question on Reddit and got a suggestion on how to add supporting of all flavor combinations by using the additional script in gradle.  It helped me, here is the link to the thread https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/g2eay6/why_more_than_two_android_flavor_dimensions_dont/

Comment: @OlegNestyuk: So if I have buildType (debug, stage, live) and productFlavors like (min16 = dimension "api", Paid having flavorDimension "version" & Free having flavorDimension "version") what would be the resulting build variants? Thanks in advance..

Comment: @Astha your final build variant will be named by ordered dimensions (same order as in your build.gradle) + buildVariant. For example, in your case, it will be "min16PaidDebug". But you have only 2 flavor dimensions, so you don't need the script.

Comment: @OlegNestyuk: my understanding is same as yours but what I'm getting is min16Debug, PaidDebug .. as if  flavorDimensions in not making any difference, any idea why?

Comment: I got my mistake ..inside productFlavors{} I was using flavorDimensions instead of dimension. Thanks for your time btw :)